# How do you control how an object is "seen" by other functions when passed as an argument?

Tags: python

For instance, say I have a Vector class like this:

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return '(%s, %s)' % (self.x, self.y)
```

If I pass this object to a function as an argument, the function sees it as

```
<__main__.Vector object at 0x02297E50>
```

Now, I can make the function *know* about the Vector in advance(so to speak), so that it knows to access it's attributes

```
def foo(vect1, vect2):
    return (vect2.x - vect1.x, vect2.y - vect1.y)
```

But what if I wanted a general function that accepts just a pair of coordinates?

```
def foo(p1, p2):
    return (p2[0] - p1[0], p2[1] -p1[1])
```

Is there a way to make an object represent itself in a specific manner? For instance, so that I could pass my Vector objects into the above general function without said function needing to know about the object type? So all that it 'sees' is the coordinates that make up the objects attributes?

Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the function sees it as ..." -- the function receives the object, what you show is the string returned by the default `__repr__`. And neither seems to have any relevance to the rest of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to adjust your object to implement certain [python hooks](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) to behave in a 'generic' way.

In your second example, you could implement the [`__getitem__` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) to make it behave like a sequence:

```
class Vector(object):
    # rest of the class

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return (self.x, self.y)[index]
```

Or to give a little demonstration:

```
>>> v = Vector(10, 20)
>>> v
<__main__.Vector object at 0x10866ad90>
>>> str(v)
'(10, 20)'
>>> v.x
10
>>> v[0]
10
```

You already discovered [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) for your self.

Comment: Exactly the functionality I was seeking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the appropriate [special methods](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names); in your case you want to implement [`__getitem__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) in order to support indexing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you might want to consider `namedtuple`:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Vector = namedtuple("Vector", "x y")
>>> v = Vector(1, 2)
>>> print v
Vector(x=1, y=2)
>>> assert v[0] == v.x
```